# I want to make a button automatically clickable without a tap in flutter. I'm also using WebView flutter:

Tags: flutter, button, webview, onclick, click

I want to make the bottom portion (that includes an ad) of the WebView clickable without a touch/tap. My WebView contains a floating ad in its bottom portion. I want to make it auto clickable without tapping it again and again. I have used IgnorePointer class. Some portion of my code is commented, you can check it also.
(Note: I'm doing this just for learning)
here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _key = UniqueKey();
    final height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    // return CustomScrollView(
    //
    //   slivers: <Widget>[
    //     SliverAppBar(
    //       title: const Text("Software Testing Help"),
    //       floating: true,
    //     ),
    //     SliverFillRemaining(
    //       child: WebView(initialUrl: "https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/digital-marketing-software/"),
    //     )
    //   ],
    // );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: height*0.08,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Center(child: Text('Software Testing Help', style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
        ),)),
      ),
      body:
         Stack(
           children: [
              Container(
                   height: height*0.90,
                   child: Expanded(
                     child: WebView(
                       initialUrl: 'https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/digital-marketing-software/',
                       key: _key,
                       javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                     ),
                   )

             ),
             Positioned(
               bottom:0,
               left: 10,
               child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: (){
                   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                     content: Text('Ad is clicked'),
                   ));
                 },
                 child: IgnorePointer(
                     ignoring: true,
                     child: Container(
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         border: Border.all(
                           color: Colors.blue
                         )
                       ),
                       height: 100,
                       width: 100,

                     ),

                 ),
               ),
             )
           ]
         )



    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it automatically by a timer, after a period of time this timer will call your function.
something like this:

```
bool? isLoading;

adClickedRunner() {
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 5), //example: after 5sec will call your task
      () async {
        isLoading = true; //to show circularProgressIndicatior for your button
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Ad is clicked'),));
        isLoading = false;
      },
    );
  }
```